# Cakephp 3 habtm with additional data

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.1, cakephp-3.x

While going through [a cakephp 3 tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/bookmarks/intro.html) about bookmarks and tags I've struggled with a problem: I want to add the third field to the `users_tags` table (tag_type: important or not), but when it saves the data it rewrites previous values to the default database value of `"tag_type"`.

Could you please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: can you please show your code?

Comment: This might help - http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-additional-data-to-the-joint-table

Comment: @manetsus my code is same as in the tutorilal

Comment: @cjquinn Thanx, but i saw that, but can't understand how to use this in tutorial's case (when i update one part of tag's list  - second part rewrites). So i want to split tags into 2 types for every user. And each user can change each list of his tags (important and not important tags). Help pls)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you added the *tag_type* column to the *users_tags* table after running bake commands, check **$_*accessible*** array value in entity file of the table i.e. **src/Model/Entity/UsersTag.php** and add an element with column name as key and *true* as value to make sure column value can be [mass assigned](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#mass-assignment)

In your [Form html](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-inputs-for-associated-data) of user add/edit page, add an input like this so that cakephp matches its value with proper column automatically when you create an entity in your controller :

```
echo $this->Form->input('tags.0._joinData.tag_type');
```